# PHP json_encode producing invalid JSON when stored in MySQL

Tags: php, json

I've googled this a bit already with no joy.  I am running a standard PHP array through `$encoded = json_encode($myArray);`

Before storing it in a MySQL database.  99% of the time this is fine but on the odd occasion the encoded JSON looks corrupted....

```
{ "value": " }
```

being stored in the database.  This is a rare occasion, in fact I can't replicate it yet in my local development environment but wouldn't you know it user can!!

The data being stored comes from a `<textarea>` on a form so the user could be putting in dodgy characters that are breaking thing somewhere, thing is I've tried every character I can think of and have even force non UTF-8 characters into it and it never causes the above.

I'm really struggling getting to the bottom of this.  First of I can't see how `json_encode` is producing the result above, perhaps figuring that out would help figure out what going on but I am stuck.

Any advice, help, pointer would be awesome,

Off I go to try to replicate it.

Comment: Try entering a huge number in value field, say 43900000034001299333 and see if it fails. I faced similar issues with encoding large integers with json (Facebook Ids). To circumvent this I used custom library Services_JSON.

Comment: To store big numbers with standard library just.. cast them to strings :)

Comment: damn, I was hopefull it could have been a size issue but the data is being stored in strings already.  I took that and tried to store a monster string and that didn't fail either.  i thought it might have been an oddity with quote encoding "" '" kinda thing but I've tried them and they are escape appropriately every time.

Comment: it's ran through json_encode then put in via a standard insert.  I've found that there is a problem elsewhere that is possibly causing it, but what is still beliverind me is why / how it's storing it as above so this is still imporant to suss.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the field in your database is long enough.  I had an issue where the json encoded data was longer than the field length and was getting truncated and causing it to be invalid...  Sometimes just looking at the encoded data it is hard to see that it is cut off on the end.  echo it out on your php page and compare it to the data that ends up in the field in the database...

Comment: It's not cut off by SQL. There's the trailing `}`.

Comment: thanks it's a text field so should more than cut the mustard for the maount of data being stored.